# Core Animation iOS 4 vs iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios4, core-animation, calayer, changelog

I have been posting Core Animation questions non-stop these days, this API is super confusing.

I have some code that animates the anchor point of a layer using:

```
        animation.fromValue     = fromValue;
        animation.toValue       = offsetToValue;
        animation.duration      = [duration doubleValue];
        animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        //update the model
        [subLayer setValue:offsetToValue forKeyPath:keyPath];

        [subLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:keyPath];
```

This animates as expected on iOS 5 (real device and simulator) and Mac 10.7 . However, when running this code on iOS 4.3 (iPad simulator, don't have a iOS 4 iPad), the anchor point animation is not executed. The anchor point changes without any animation.

I am baffled by this, and I have absolutely no idea how to even approach the problem! I tried searching for a change log, known issues, ... etc. No luck with that.

Please advise what should I do now?

**edit:**

Forgot to mention, that animating the transform and position using this code works on both iOS4 and iOS5 (!!)

**edit:**

Sorry, I realized my question is implicit. I have an iOS app that must support iOS4.0+. If I were supporting iOS5 only, I wouldn't even care about this problem.

Comment: The docs make it seem like the anchor point should have been animatable since 2.0

Comment: I seem to recall that with iOS 4 you need to update your model only after the animations have completed (e.g., you're making the call to animate and update the model property in the same run loop).

Comment: The [API diff from 4.3 to 5.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/index.html) doesn't mention any updates except the CAEmitterLayer in the entire QuartzCore

Comment: @isaac I'll try what you said, thanks, however, remember that position and transform animations are working perfectly. *EDIT*: The anchorPoint doesn't move at all now. The rest of the animations (position, transform) animate then go back to original position (as expected because I didn't update the model).

Comment: Can you share the code where you construct your animation and values?

Comment: Sure, here is a test project I did to make sure my original project didn't have other errors that caused this. http://pastebin.com/ddwTcgGz . (Watch out for the NSImage #define). Just paste this in a new iPad single view project, in the viewcontroller.